# Angular2 triggering Host listeners on a button click

Tags: angular, service, listener, directive, subject

I need to trigger Host listeners after a click of a certain button. The host listeners should then highlight any hovered element on page and listen to mouse clicks which would open a modal. Problem is that when I start listening for mouse clicks and do click, the modal sometimes doesn't open until I click the button that triggers the Host listeners. Also the highlighted elements get 'stuck' and stay highlighted after a mouse click trying to open a modal.

Is it an asynchronous problem? Any idea how to fix this, please?

Highlight.directive

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input, Output, EventEmitter, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';

import { FeedbackService } from './feedback.service';

import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Directive({
  selector: 'a, abbr, address, article, body, br, button, div, form, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, header, hr, i, iframe, img, ' +
  'input, label, li, link, meta, nav, object, ol, option, output, p, param, pre, section, select, small, source, span,' +
  'summary, table, tbody, td, textarea, tfoot, th, thead, time, title, tr, u, ul, video'
})
export class HighlightDirective {
    elementsArray: string[];
    listening: boolean = false;
    allowClick: boolean = false;

    @Output() notifyParent: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

    @Input() start: boolean;

    constructor(private el: ElementRef, private feedbackService: FeedbackService) {
        this.elementsArray = ["a", 'abbr', 'address', 'article', 'body', 'br', 'button', 'div', 'form', 'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5'
        , 'h6', 'header', 'hr', 'i', 'iframe', 'img', 'input', 'label', 'li', 'link', 'meta', 'nav', 'object', 'ol', 'option'
        , 'output', 'p', 'param', 'pre', 'section', 'select', 'small', 'source', 'span', 'summary', 'table', 'tbody', 'td'
        , 'textarea', 'tfoot', 'th', 'thead', 'time', 'title', 'tr', 'u', 'ul', 'video'];

        feedbackService.myBool$.subscribe((newBool: boolean) => { this.listening = newBool; });
    }

    //check: boolean = false;

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
        console.log(changes);
        this.listening = true;
    }

    public getElement(): ElementRef {
        return this.el;
    }

    public startFeedback(): void {
        this.listening = true;
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        //Observable.fromEvent(document, 'mouseenter').subscribe(data => {});
    }

    //@HostListener('click') onClick() {
    @HostListener('document:click', ['$event.target']) onClick(targetElement) {
        //if (this.listening && this.allowClick) {
        if (this.feedbackService.boolSubject.getValue() == true && this.allowClick) {
            //document.getElementById('feedbackButton').click();

            console.log(11);
            this.notifyParent.emit(targetElement);

            //this.feedbackService.boolSubject.next(false);

            this.el.nativeElement.style.boxShadow = null;
            this.listening = false;
            this.start = false;
            this.allowClick = false;
        }
    }

    @HostListener('mouseenter', ['$event.target']) onMouseEnter(targetElement) {
        //if(this.listening) {
        if (this.feedbackService.boolSubject.getValue() == true) {

            if(!this.allowClick)
                this.allowClick = true;

            targetElement.parentNode.style.boxShadow = null;  
            if(targetElement.className != 'container')
                targetElement.style.boxShadow = '0 0 0 5px yellow';
        }
    }

    @HostListener('mouseleave', ['$event.target']) onMouseLeave(targetElement) {
        //if(this.listening) {
        if (this.feedbackService.boolSubject.getValue()) {
            targetElement.style.boxShadow = null;
            if(targetElement.parentNode.className != 'container')
                targetElement.parentNode.style.boxShadow = '0 0 0 5px yellow';

            let check = false;

            for (let entry of this.elementsArray) {
                if (targetElement.parentNode.nodeName == entry.toUpperCase()) {
                    check = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!check)
                targetElement.parentNode.style.boxShadow = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Feedback.service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import {AsyncSubject} from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class FeedbackService {
    myBool$: Observable<boolean>;

    public boolSubject: BehaviorSubject<boolean>;

    private checkValue: boolean = false;

    constructor() {
        this.boolSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
        this.myBool$ = this.boolSubject.asObservable();
    }

    startFeedback(): void {
        this.boolSubject.next(true);
        //this.checkValue = true;
    }

    endFeedback(): void {
        this.boolSubject.next(false);
        //this.checkValue = false;
    }

    getValue(): boolean {
        //this.boolSubject.next(true);
        return this.checkValue;
    }
}
```

App.component

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, QueryList, Input, ViewChildren, ContentChildren } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

import { HighlightDirective } from './highlight.directive';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

import { ModalComponent } from './modal.component';
import { FeedbackModalComponent } from './feedbackModal.component';
import { FeedbackService } from './feedback.service';


@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <div class="container">
    <h1 myHighlight="orange">{{title}}</h1>
    <nav>
      <a routerLink="/dashboard" routerLinkActive="active">Dashboard</a>
      <a routerLink="/heroes" routerLinkActive="active">Heroes</a>
      <a routerLink="/secret-heroes" *ngIf="authService.loggedIn()" routerLinkActive="active">Secret Heroes</a>
      <a (click)=authService.login() *ngIf="!authService.loggedIn()">Log In</a>
      <a (click)=authService.logout() *ngIf="authService.loggedIn()">Log Out</a>
      <a (click)=giveFeedback() (notifyParent)="getNotification($event)">Give Feedback</a>

    <my-feedback-modal>
    </my-feedback-modal>

      </nav>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Tour of Heroes';
  startFeedback = false;
  feedbackElement: ElementRef;

  @ViewChildren(HighlightDirective) highlightDirs: QueryList<HighlightDirective>;

  @ViewChild(FeedbackModalComponent) feedbackModal: FeedbackModalComponent;

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private el: ElementRef, private feedbackService: FeedbackService) {  }

  clickedElement:BehaviorSubject<ElementRef> = new BehaviorSubject(this.el);

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    //this.clickedElement.next(this.highlightDir.getElement().nativeElement.nodeName);
  }

  getNotification(evt) {
        // Do something with the notification (evt) sent by the child!
      console.log(evt);
      this.feedbackModal.show(evt);
    }

  giveFeedback(): void {
      //this.startFeedback = true;
//    this.highlightDirs.forEach((highlightDir: HighlightDirective) => {
//       highlightDir.startFeedback();
//    });
    this.feedbackService.startFeedback();
  }
}
```

FeedbackModal.component

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, Input } from '@angular/core';

import { ModalComponent } from './modal.component';

import { Hero } from './hero';
import { HeroService } from './hero.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { FeedbackService } from './feedback.service';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'my-feedback-modal',
  template: `
  <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" [ngClass]="{'in': visibleAnimate}"
      [ngStyle]="{'display': visible ? 'block' : 'none', 'opacity': visibleAnimate ? 1 : 0}">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          Element <{{ elementName }}>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div id="first-row"></div><br>
          <form action="">
            <label for="rating">Rating</label>
            <div class="row" >
             <div class="col-xs-12">
                <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1"> 1
                </label>
                <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2"> 2
                </label>
                <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio3" value="option3"> 3
                </label>
                <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio4" value="option4"> 4
                </label>
                <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio5" value="option5"> 5
                </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <label for="comment">Comment</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="hero.name" placeholder="name" name="name" rows="3"></textarea><br>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="hide()">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="save()">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['modal.component.css']
})

export class FeedbackModalComponent {
  public visible = false;
  private visibleAnimate = false;
  private elementName: any;
  private appendingElement: any;

    @Input() hero: Hero;
    error: any;

  @ViewChild(ModalComponent) modal: ModalComponent;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private heroService: HeroService,
    private router: Router, private feedbackService: FeedbackService) {  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    //this.clickedElement.next(this.highlightDir.getElement().nativeElement.nodeName);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
      this.hero = new Hero();
  }

  public show(el: any): void {
      this.feedbackService.boolSubject.next(false);
    //this.feedbackService.endFeedback();

    this.el = el;
    this.elementName = el.nodeName;

//    this.appendingElement = document.getElementById('first-row');
//    let cloneEl = el.cloneNode(true);
//    this.appendingElement.appendChild(cloneEl);

    this.visible = true;
    setTimeout(() => this.visibleAnimate = true);
  }

  public hide(): void {
//      this.appendingElement.removeChild(this.appendingElement.firstChild);

    this.visibleAnimate = false;
    setTimeout(() => this.visible = false, 300);
  }

  save(): void {
    this.heroService
        .save(this.hero)
        .then(hero => {
          this.hero = hero; // saved hero, w/ id if new
          if(this.router.url == '/heroes')
            window.location.reload();
          else
            this.hide();
        })
        .catch(error => this.error = error); // TODO: Display error message
  }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have errors?

Comment: No, I don't have any errors.

Comment: If the event bubbles, this should work fine when you click anywhere inside the component.

Comment: Well it doesn't work fine. Half the time it does but the other half it creates the problem I talked about. When I click the 'Give Feedback' button, all elements when hovered are highlighted but when I click again to open a modal, sometimes it doesn't open it, makes the element permanently highlighted until I hover over it again and the modal gets opened only by the 'Give Feedback' button and occasionally by some random element after a random amount of clicks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out. The only working solution I found seems to be scrapping entire service and directive and remaking app.component by adding Renderers that listenGlobal to any changes in the document. It also makes the code neater but no idea if it's a good practice.

Updated App.component

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, Renderer, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

import { FeedbackModalComponent } from './feedbackModal.component';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { NotificationsService } from 'angular2-notifications';


@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
    <div class="container">
        <h1 myHighlight="orange">{{title}}</h1>
        <nav>
            <a routerLink="/dashboard" routerLinkActive="active">Dashboard</a>
            <a routerLink="/heroes" routerLinkActive="active">Heroes</a>
            <a routerLink="/secret-heroes" *ngIf="authService.loggedIn()" routerLinkActive="active">Secret Heroes</a>
            <a (click)=authService.login() *ngIf="!authService.loggedIn()">Log In</a>
            <a (click)=authService.logout() *ngIf="authService.loggedIn()">Log Out</a>
            <a (click)=giveFeedback() (notifyParent)="getNotification($event)">Give Feedback</a>

            <my-feedback-modal>
            </my-feedback-modal>

            </nav>
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>

            <simple-notifications [options]="options"></simple-notifications>
      </div>
    `,
    styleUrls: ['app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'Tour of Heroes';
    public options = {
        timeOut: 0,
        showProgressBar: true,
        pauseOnHover: false,
        clickToClose: true,
        maxLength: 50,
        animate: "fromRight"
    };

    lastEvent: any;
    listening: boolean = false;
    allowClick: boolean = false;
    globalListenFunc: Function;
    globalListenFunc2: Function;

    @ViewChild(FeedbackModalComponent) feedbackModal: FeedbackModalComponent;

    constructor(private authService: AuthService, private el: ElementRef, private router: Router, 
        private notificationsService: NotificationsService, private renderer: Renderer) 
    {  
        this.lastEvent = el;
        this.lastEvent.style = [];
        this.lastEvent.style.boxShadow = null;
    }

    addListeners() {
        this.globalListenFunc = this.renderer.listenGlobal('document', 'click', (event) => {
            if (this.listening == true && this.allowClick) {
                this.notificationsService.remove();
                this.feedbackModal.show(event.srcElement);

                // FIND A BETTER FIX
                this.router.navigateByUrl('/dashboard');

                this.el.nativeElement.style.boxShadow = null;
                this.listening = false;
                this.allowClick = false;

                this.removeListeners();
            }
        });

        this.globalListenFunc2 = this.renderer.listenGlobal('document', 'mousemove', (event) => {
            if (this.listening == true && this.lastEvent != event.srcElement) {
                if(!this.allowClick)
                    this.allowClick = true;

                this.lastEvent.style.boxShadow = '';
                if(event.srcElement.className != 'container') {
                    event.srcElement.style.boxShadow = '0 0 0 5px yellow';
                }
                this.lastEvent = event.srcElement;
            }
        });
    }

    removeListeners() {
        this.globalListenFunc();
        this.globalListenFunc2();
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        // Remove the listeners!
        this.globalListenFunc();
        this.globalListenFunc2();
    }

    giveFeedback(): void {
        this.notificationsService.info(
            'Feedback',
            "Choose an element you would like to rate.",
            this.options
        )
        this.listening = true;
        this.addListeners();
    }
}
```