# Is possible to set HostListener on specific button?

Tags: angular

I would like to call some method, when **ESC**ape button will be pressed. I did it in this way:

```
@HostListener('window:keydown', ['$event'])
clickEscape(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    //if ESC was pressed
    if(event.keyCode === 27) {
        this.someMethod();
    }
}
```

But *clickEscape* method will be called every time, when user click any button on keybord. And my question is:

Is it possible to set HostListener so that method will be called only when detect ESCape button? 
I was thinking about something in style:

```
@HostListener('window:keydown["ESCAPE"]')
someMethod() {
    //...
}
```

Is there similar event?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41420153/angular2-triggering-host-listeners-on-a-button-click

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can indeed use `keydown.escape`:

```
@HostListener('window:keydown.escape')
someMethod() {
    //...
}
```

Comment: Would it work with `@HostListener('window:keydown.${key}')`, with template string? Can't use them or comment will go nuts.. hehehe

Comment: @SrAxi No, that's not possible. An annotation (`@HostListener`) is set before any component variable is known

Comment: @PierreDuc, Can I be sure, that every browser will be interpret '.escape' in the same way? keyCode look safer

Comment: @JaroslawK. The key bindings in angular are normalised to be used in any browser back to `IE9`